# Movie portfolio Image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am developing my portfolio website. My Website designs are very big in size 1600x900 min because i design them on wide screen for better view.

I am using Jquery for making the picture big. Now when it gets big it cover all the screen and cover my website.

I want some thing that when the picture gets big in a box i can move it using my mouse, so that it will not cover whole screen.

This is the code below.

```
<div class="two-one last">
    <h2>Recent Work</h2>

    <ul class="recent">
        <li class="image"><img src="./example/recent1.jpg" alt="Image"><a href="./example/recent1_b.jpg" class="link" rel="pretty" title="Vision Plus Logo">View</a></li>
        <li class="image last"><img src="./example/recent2.jpg" alt="Image"><a href="./example/recent2_b.jpg" class="link" rel="pretty" title="Rahman & Rahman Dental Surgeons">View</a></li>
        <li class="image"><img src="./example/recent3.jpg" alt="Image"><a href="./example/recent3_b.jpg" class="link" rel="pretty">View</a></li>
        <li class="image last"><img src="./example/recent4.jpg" alt="Image"><a href="./example/recent4_b.jpg" class="link" rel="pretty">View</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See this image
http://i40.tinypic.com/29lfbs1.jpg

You see the preview when you first click on the image. Then if you click the button at the top corner of the image. It will get full size, I just want it to be show in current box but the image will be full not the box. So then I can drag the image where ever I want in the box to see the full image without losing any quality.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-ui has some really good implementations. You can download/use jQuery-ui for free

Check: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

With a html source like:

```
<div class="two-one last">
  <h2>Recent Work</h2>

  <ul class="recent">
    <li class="image">
      <img src="./example/recent1.jpg" alt="Image">
      <a href="./example/recent1_b.jpg" class="link">View</a>
    </li>

    <!-- more li here -->

   </ul>
 </div>
```

You can then hide the images by default with CSS and a simple click event to show the image.

```
var link = $('.link');

link.click(function()
{
  var big_image_url = $(this).attr('href');

  var big_img = $('<img id="draggable">').attr('src', big_image_url);

  big_img.load(function()
  {
     $("body").prepend(big_img);
     $('#draggable').draggable();
   });

   return false; // To prevent a href from working
 });
```

A full webpage (very simple) implementation would look like this:

http://pastebin.com/FtjaiGpa

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rid8.jpg


You see the preview when you 1st click on the image. Then if you click the button at the top corner of the image. it will get full size, i just want it to be show in current box but the image will be full not the box. So then i can drag the image where ever i want in the box to see the full image without loosing any quality

Comment: I am affreaid I do not really understand you :( 

What I posted will show some small images, when clicked it shows a full version of the image (well it will show an image you provide the url for) and it can be dragged around. If you want to display it in a box that is purely presentation, so you could add with css

`img#draggable {padding:12px; background:#fff; border-radius:9px;}`

or something. But to understand you better maybe try to implement some javascript and then add this to your original question so we can maybe see where it is going wrong?